# Vulnerabilidad context.getDir() android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al momento de saber si existe un archivo. Lo que estoy usando es

```
final String SAFEDIR=String.valueOf(usuario.getUserName());
File dir = new File(String.valueOf(ctx.getDir(SAFEDIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
if (dir.exists()){}
```

solo que usaurio.getUserName() lo traigo de un editText y esto me esta marcando como vulnerabilidad en kiuwan, pero no entiendo porque. En el editText pongo esta linea para que solo acepte esos caracteres

```
 android:digits="0123456789*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm"
```

Y esto es lo que dice kiuwan al momento al respecto de la vulnerabilidad:
Esto es lo que dice kiuwan : El software utiliza una entrada externa para construir un nombre de ruta destinado a identificar un archivo o directorio que se encuentra debajo de un directorio principal restringido, pero el software no neutraliza adecuadamente los elementos especiales dentro del nombre de la ruta que pueden hacer que el nombre de la ruta se resuelva en una ubicación fuera del directorio restringido.

En un servidor de aplicaciones, si la configuración del servidor de aplicaciones no restringe el acceso a archivos fuera de ciertos directorios restringidos, el atacante puede obtener archivos confidenciales, y si el archivo está escrito con contenido controlado por la entrada del usuario, el atacante puede cambiar los archivos de configuración (como web .xml entre otros), contenidos web ('desfiguración web') o bibliotecas (para ataques de inyección de código más insidiosos). El acceso a los archivos del sistema (la contraseña habitual / etc / en los sistemas Unix / Linux) también podría permitirse con los permisos de la cuenta del servidor de aplicaciones.

Se recomienda, además de garantizar que los archivos que dependen de la entrada controlada por el usuario no salgan de los directorios previstos, que la cuenta del sistema operativo tenga los permisos mínimos, para reducir el impacto de un ataque transversal de ruta exitoso.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta el mensaje que advierte sobre la vulnerabilidad.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, revisa por favor [ask], recuerda aportar màs informaciòn por favor, como comenta A. Cedano, es importante agregar que mensaje se muestra ? saludos.

Comment: actualice la pregunta agregando la descripción de la vulnerabilidad, muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo